# Sign in with.... OAuth 1.0 Authentication with SPA + RESTful API

Tags: angularjs, rest, symfony, twitter, oauth

Is this generally possible to authorize with OAuth 1.0 from Single-Page-App? I have an app working with RESTful back-end (Symfony). There was no problem with authentication with facebook, but I have huge problem how to approach the login with twitter, since it is only OAuth 1.0.

Does anyone have some experience with this and know how to approach this problem? I am also suprised that there is no service for Angular.js usign OAuth 1.0 ...

The way I see this - the API can send a request for login window - but then - how can it send it to my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an OAuth library supporting both OAuth 1 & 2 to solve the problem. If you are working with Symfony, there is this bundle which should fit your needs:

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle